# Return to ImmersiveSticky after FocusChanged from Entry Field

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I have a Xamarin Forms App, On the main screen, I would like it to be full screen with Bottom Nav Bar and Status Bar Hidden.

I have been able to accomplish it, but I have another page I navigate to with some entry fields, once I click on the Entry field the bars return and will not hide again when I return to my main page, I then have to restart the app to have it in full screen again. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

This is the code to hide the Status and Navigation Bar on app launch...

```cs
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
    ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

    int uiOptions = (int)Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility;

    uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.LowProfile;
    uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.Fullscreen;
    uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.HideNavigation;
    uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.LayoutHideNavigation;
    uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.ImmersiveSticky;
    uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.LayoutStable;
    uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.LayoutFullscreen;

    Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)uiOptions;

    LoadApplication(new App());
}
```

I have tried to override `OnResume` with the code above but it never hits the `OnResume` once the app is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement it in Xamarin.forms by using **DependencyService** .

#### in Forms ,create an interface

```
public interface IStatusBar
{
    void HideStatusBar();
    void ShowStatusBar();
}
```

#### in Android

We can use the plugin [CurrentActivityPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin) .

Simply call the Init method on OnCreate of MainActivity

```
base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
```

```
using Plugin.CurrentActivity;
using Android.Views;
using App16.Droid;


[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(StatusBarImplementation))]
namespace App16.Droid
{
    public class StatusBarImplementation : IStatusBar
    {
        public StatusBarImplementation()
        {
        }

        WindowManagerFlags _originalFlags;

        #region IStatusBar implementation

        public void HideStatusBar()
        {
            var activity = CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity;
            var attrs = activity.Window.Attributes;
            _originalFlags = attrs.Flags;
            attrs.Flags |= Android.Views.WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen;
            activity.Window.Attributes = attrs;
        }

        public void ShowStatusBar()
        {
            var activity = CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity;
            var attrs = activity.Window.Attributes;
            attrs.Flags = _originalFlags;
            activity.Window.Attributes = attrs;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

#### in iOS

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(StatusBarImplementation))]
namespace xxx.iOS
{
    public class StatusBarImplementation : IStatusBar
    {
        public StatusBarImplementation()
        {
        }
      
        public void HideStatusBar()
        {
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarHidden = true;
        }

        public void ShowStatusBar()
        {
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarHidden = false;
        }

     
    }
}
```

#### And in your MainPage

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
   base.OnAppearing();
   NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
   // hide
   DependencyService.Get<IStatusBar>().HideStatusBar();
}

protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
   base.OnDisappearing();
   NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, true);
   // show
   DependencyService.Get<IStatusBar>().ShowStatusBar();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help .

Comment: Happy coding :)

Answer (score -1):

You can add a flag in this way.

```cs
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<string>(this, "showBar", (sender) =>
    {

        this.Window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);
        this.Window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.KeepScreenOn);

    });
    TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
    ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

    this.Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);
    this.Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.KeepScreenOn);
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

    AnimationViewRenderer.Init();
    ButtonCircleRenderer.Init();

    CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

    LoadApplication(new App());
}
```